# Which error will be handled by express error and which by uncaughtException error handler?

Tags: node.js, express, uncaught-exception

In my services using express nodejs. I knew about the express error handler, the callback function with err first

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next)
```

And We can handle the uncaughtException also by

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {}
```

In fact, some uncaughtException will go to express error handler not uncaughtException handler.

Please help to tell me which error will be handled by express, which by uncaughtException handler?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you throw an exception (`throw new Error(...)`) in a function that was directly called from Express, it will be catched and forwarded it to your error handler. This happens because there's a `try-catch` block around your code.

```
app.get("/throw", function(request, response, next) {
    throw new Error("Error thrown in scope of this function. Express.js will delegate it to error handler.")
});
```

When you throw an exception in a function that is not directly called from Express (deferred or async code), there's no catch block available to catch this error and handle it properly. For example, if you have code that gets executed asynchronously:

```
app.get("/uncaught", function(request, response, next) {
    // Simulate async callback using setTimeout.
    // (Querying the database for example).
    setTimeout(function() {
        throw new Error("Error thrown without surrounding try/catch. Express.js cannot catch it.");
    }, 250);
});
```

This error won't be catched by Express (and forwarded to the error handler) because there's no wrapping try/catch block around this code. In this case, the uncaught exception handler will be triggered instead.

In general, if you encounter an error from which you cannot recover, use [`next(error)`](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html) to properly forward this error to your error handler middleware:

```
app.get("/next", function(request, response, next) {
    // Simulate async callback using setTimeout.
    // (Querying the database for example).
    setTimeout(function() {
        next(new Error("Error always forwarded to the error handler."));
    }, 250);
});
```

Below is a full example to play around with:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get("/throw", function(request, response, next) {
    throw new Error("Error thrown in scope of this function. Express.js will delegate it to error handler.")
});

app.get("/uncaught", function(request, response, next) {
    // Simulate async callback using setTimeout.
    // (Querying the database for example).
    setTimeout(function() {
        throw new Error("Error thrown without surrounding try/catch. Express.js cannot catch it.");
    }, 250);
});

app.get("/next", function(request, response, next) {
    // Simulate async callback using setTimeout.
    // (Querying the database for example).
    setTimeout(function() {
        next(new Error("Error always forwarded to the error handler."));
    }, 250);
});


app.use(function(error, request, response, next) {
    console.log("Error handler: ", error);
});

process.on("uncaughtException", function(error) {
    console.log("Uncaught exception: ", error);
});

// Starting the web server
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what is directly call from Express ? :D.
I'm newbie so many things to knows
Many thanks :d

Comment: I updated my answer with a full example, hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer !!!
In additional, app.get or app.post (something like that) when passing to router api of express, their errors will be caught by express also (it happens in my project :D)

Comment: You're welcome! As a final step, can you accept my answer? Thanks!